# How can I unpack variadic template, so as to initialize respective members?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, argument-unpacking

I am new to variadic templates and packed arguments and all.
I want to have a "entity component system" in my program, and while trying to add component to the entity, I came to realize that my attempt has a major flaw.

Anyways here is my failed attempt.

```
struct A{
    float x;
    float y;
    
    A(float _x, float _y):x(_x), y(_y){}
};

struct B{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    
    B(float _x, float _y, float _z):x(_x), y(_y), z(_z){}
};

struct Entity{
    A* a = NULL;
    B* b = NULL;
    
    Entity(){}
    
    template<typename T, typename... args>
    void Add(args... _args){
        if(typeid(T) == typeid(A))
            a = new A(_args...);
        else if(typeid(T) == typeid(B))
            b = new B(_args...);
        else
            throw("Invalid component added");
    }
};
```

And implementation looks like this..

```
Entity ent;
ent.Add<A>(12.24f, 123.246f);
ent.Add<B>(1.f, 1.2f, 1.23f);
```

I want the implementation to work somehow.. what has to be changed for it??

Comment: You want use [`std:: is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and `if constexpr`.

Comment: You can massage this into a compilable form but it doesn't make a lot of sense. Separate AddA and AddB functions do the job better in every way.

Comment: If this is part of actual code, just use `std::variant` instead. The constructor can be called with a `std::in_place_type<T>` instance as 1st parameter. You can use assignment, if after construction anything needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the following** (all in compile time):

1. [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to check if 2 types are the same (requires `#include <type_traits>`).
2. [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) to branch based on it (c++17 onwards).
3. [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) if you want to get a compilation error if `Add` is instatiated with types other than `A` or `B` (see note about it below).

**Your modified code:**

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    float x;
    float y;

    A(float _x, float _y) :x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

struct B {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    B(float _x, float _y, float _z) :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}
};

struct Entity {
    A* a = nullptr;
    B* b = nullptr;

    Entity() {}

    template<typename T, typename... args>
    void Add(args... _args) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, A>)
            a = new A(_args...);
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, B>)
            b = new B(_args...);
        else
            //static_assert(!sizeof(T), "T must be A or B");  // Enable this line to get a compilation error in this case
            throw("Invalid component added");
    }
};

int main() {
    Entity ent;
    ent.Add<A>(12.24f, 123.246f);
    ent.Add<B>(1.f, 1.2f, 1.23f);
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I used the standard `nullptr` which is recommended instead of `NULL`.
2. Using a simple `static_assert(false, ...)` is not guaranteed to work for the reason mentioned in the article in @RemyLebeau's comment ([How can I create a type-dependent expression that is always false?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553)).
   One of the solution suggested in that article is to use `static_assert(!sizeof(T), ...)` assuming sizeof is never 0. The article also suggests a slightly more complicated solution that avoids this assumption.

[**Live demo - Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/z/4hPeoaPfz)

Comment: Note that `static_assert(false)` doesn't work as expected in this case. It will fail as soon as it is parsed by the compiler. To delay the error until the template is instantiated, you need to use a [type-dependent expression that is always false](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553).

Comment: @RemyLebeau interesting link. However - gcc seems to compile it OK (enable the static_assert in my Godbolt link and see). It is a bug in gcc ? Or the issue in the article is resticted to lambdas (which is what is mentioned there) ?

Comment: The issue is not related to lambdas. When I run your Godbolt example using gcc 11.x or 12.x (or 10.x with `-std=c++17` specified), the `static_assert` fails immediately as expected. The code runs OK in gcc 13.x, though. So, either this is a bug in gcc 13.x, or they intentionally changed the behavior.

Comment: Using `static_assert` works fine in all compilers, you just have to use it *correctly*, which your example is not (but gcc is letting you get away with it)

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right. Updated my answer.